# Teradata CHARINDEX version

Tags: teradata, charindex

I have to convert this SQL server statement in Teradata. What would you use for CHARINDEX?

```
SELECT * from MyTeraDataView WHERE CHARINDEX(cast(GroupID as varchar(5)),@Groups) > 0
```

I am trying to SELECT rows which have GroupIDs in @Groups. For example @Groups has values like '2345','6543','7854', etc.

Comment: Running a query like that on Teradata is going to be really, really bad.  A function call like that makes the whole query non-sargable, so you're going to end up doing a full table scan.  If it's in teradata, that's probably a LOT of rows.  Reconsider your plan.

Comment: It will return just 50 rows or so- not bad at all. Problem is that @Groups is coming thru a process from SQL server to Teradata and I am having hard times figuring out how to write the WHERE clause

Comment: `CHARINDEX` is proprietaty MS syntax for Standard SQL's `POSITION` (Teradata supports an enhanced version, too: `INSTR`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function "POSITION":

```
SELECT * from MyTeraDataView WHERE POSITION (cast(GroupID as varchar(5)) IN @Group) > 0
```